# How to get rid of LOH Fragmentations and Optimize the code

Tags: c#, heap-memory, large-files

I'm having a simple thread running to clean some cache files from a directory. Most of the files are large objects more than 80KBytes. There are about 2000 files like that in the directory. The is as shown below.

```
while (true)
{
  if (Directory.Exists(CACHE_PATH))
  {
    List<FileInfo> filesList = new DirectoryInfo(CACHE_PATH).GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
    long directorySize = filesList.Sum(e => e.Length);

    if (directorySize > CACHE_MAX_SIZE)
    {
      filesList.Sort(new FileInfoAccessTimeComparer());
      while (directorySize > CACHE_MAX_SIZE * 0.75)
      {
        directorySize -= filesList[0].Length;
        filesList[0].Delete();
        filesList.RemoveAt(0);
      }
    }
    filesList.Clear();
    filesList = null;
  }
  Thread.Sleep(CACHE_CLEANUP_INTERVAL);
}
```

I want to know whether this approach cause any LOH Fragmentation, any other Type of Enumerable type I Should use other than List (Such as ArrayPool).

Additionally, is that a good way to use

```
List<FileInfo> filesList = new DirectoryInfo(CACHE_PATH).GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

Instead of

```
FileInfo[] fileInfos = new DirectoryInfo(CACHE_PATH).GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
List<FileInfo> filesList = fileInfos.ToList();
```

Comment: `Additionally, is that a good way to use` They are the same - it doesn't matter if the `ToList` is on its own line or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Large Object Heap concern, since your underlying array is small (only a few thousand entries) and your `FileInfo` objects are small. `FileInfo` is just metadata - it isn't the **contents** of the files.

There are no glaring issues with your code. You could avoid using `RemoveAt` to save your many (behind the scenes) unnecessary array allocation / resize operations. The below code would achieve that (and also avoid the need for the `ToList` call):

```
while (true)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(CACHE_PATH))
    {
        var filesList = new DirectoryInfo(CACHE_PATH).GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        long directorySize = filesList.Sum(e => e.Length);

        if (directorySize > CACHE_MAX_SIZE)
        {
            filesList.OrderBy(z => z, new FileInfoAccessTimeComparer()).TakeWhile(z => directorySize > CACHE_MAX_SIZE * 0.75)
                .ForEach(z =>
                {
                    z.Delete();
                    directorySize -= z.Length;
                });
        }
        filesList = null;
    }
    Thread.Sleep(CACHE_CLEANUP_INTERVAL);
}
```

*Note to use `ForEach` like I have you will need to install [MoreLINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/). If that is an issue, use a `foreach` loop instead.*

Comment: What if few Thousands increased to 80 or hundred thousands may be more?
What will be the impact?

Comment: You'll be fine if you use my suggested change. Large Object Heap kicks in around 80K. Which isn't **that** much memory. And ultimately if memory gets low the GC will take care of it. So, in summary, the LOH is very unlikely to get involved. But if it does my code will likely perform better (since there should be fewer arrays allocated due to getting rid of `RemoveAt`).

Comment: If you are concerned, give it a try @DimuthRuwantha . http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant

Comment: I would rather not like to install any nuget packages at this moment.

Comment: @DimuthRuwantha In that case replace my use of `ForEach` with a `foreach` loop. The rest of the code would be unchanged.

Comment: For the downvoters I'd love your feedback on how to improve the answer!